# Convergence of regular polygon to circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, algebraic-geometry

Let $P_3, P_4, \ldots, P_n$ a polygon sequence, when $n \rightarrow \infty$ this sequence converge to circle (by area)?

I used two ways:

1. I used the parametrization $x = rcos(\pi i/n)$ and $y = rcos(\pi i/n)$, where $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $r$ is the radius;
2. I apply the parametrization in Shoelaces' equation to area of polygon ($n$-sides) given by $A = \frac{1}{2}\left|\sum_{i = 1}^{N} y_{i}(x_{i+1}-x_{i-1})\right|$.

I demonstrated. But I need a reference for demonstration can be paper, book, thesis etc.

Comment: Instead of using the shoelace formula, you could take $A_n$ equal to $n$ times the area of an isosceles triangle with vertex angle $2\pi/n$ and equal side length $r$. Your problem is then reduced to finding $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin(2\pi/n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you mean that $P_n$ is a regular *n*-gon inscribed in the circle.

Split the circle, and the polygon inside it, into its top and bottom halves.  Observe that the top half of the polygon is a trapezoidal Riemann sum for the upper semi-circle and that the bottom half of the polygon is a trapezoidal Riemann sum for the lower semi-circle.

At this point you can apply the standard theory of trapezoidal Riemann sums, which is covered in every calculus textbook -- just look up "trapezoidal" in the index.